# How can I build a subscription product selling system with drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, notifications

I'm creating an Drupal [commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) website, I want to sell subscription to internet via satellite service.
Sincerely I'm confused and I don't know what modules I should to use for this kind of product.

Comment: Follow up question on the new edit. When you say "drupal-commerce website", does "commerce" refer to the module commerce specifically, or is the word meant in a more general context? If it refers to the module, can you please indicate that by linking to it?

Comment: Yes, I mean a website based on the drupal commerce module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying modules and searching, I found this module [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license):

> Provides a framework for selling access to local or remote resources.
>
> In practice, this means that there’s a license entity, usually created during order checkout, that holds information about accessing the purchased resource, and it has a status and an optional expiration date. This allows selling access to anything from files to node types, or perhaps ZenDesk tickets and accounts on remote sites, all using a common API, while always having a record of the purchased access for the benefit of both the store administrator and the customer.

And a helpful explanation in this screecast:[Tech Talks - Commerce License](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcLitdbIxZM) .

Answer (score 0):

Check [Commerce subscription products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_sp) module.

> Features
>
> - Sell subscriptions via products.
> - Administers can view and customize the subscription validity per user    if they have necessary field permissions.
> - There are two "rule sets" (Subscription starts, Subscription ends)    that make customizing the subscription easy, e.g. one could    easily    add rules for granting/removing a user role.
> - Subscriptions expire automatically once the validity time is reached    thanks to the Rules Scheduler (requires cron to function).
> - Views integration, as the subscription validity date is implemented    as account field.
> - Custom notifications like "Warning: Subscription expires in 2 weeks"    can be easily configured using Rules and the Rules    Scheduler.